# Can it possible add <span> tag after menu item name in Shopify?

Tags: html, css, tags, shopify

Can it possible to add the `<span>` tag after the menu item name I want to add an icon, not a using before the content please help me how to add `<span>` tag any idea please let me know in `Shopify` I attachment screenshot of what I want. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: either using JS or parse and modify the HTML code in liquid, otherwise from the backend you can't

Comment: Shopify linklists item name is not html rendered.
Find where the linklist is and use `menu::after` to generate the icon. Update your questions and insert the code after if you needed help.